# tkinter Treeview indentation

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm building a tree structure (see image link below) within an application and want to adjust the indentation of the children within the tree. I've used a `style.configure` to set the indent level (see code example below). But this seems to only control the indention of the first child under the parent level. I would like to set the indention for all the child levels to the same.

Here is a snippet of the code I am using. It shows the style configuration and the definition of the first tab shown in the image:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Mystyle.Treeview",  indent=15,  font=(self.tree_font, self.tree_font_size, 'normal') )
style.layout("Mystyle.Treeview", [('Mystyle.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})])  # Remove the borders


self.NBframe = Frame(self.navFrame, width=tree_display_width)
self.NBframe.pack(expand = TRUE, fill=Y)
self.NBframe_h_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.NBframe, orient='horizontal')
self.NBframe_h_scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
self.NBframe_v_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.NBframe, orient='vertical')
self.NBframe_v_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
self.navControl = ttk.Notebook(self.NBframe, width=tree_display_width)
self.navControl.pack(expand = TRUE, fill=Y)
self.navControl.bind('<Button-1>', self._on_navControl_click)

self.tabVendors = Frame(self.navControl, background="white", borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED, width=tree_display_width)
self.tabVendors.pack()
self.Vendors_tab_name = "Vendors"
self.navControl.add(self.tabVendors, text=self.Vendors_tab_name)
self.Vendors_tab_index = self.navControl.index(self.tabVendors)
self.tabVendors_tree = ttk.Treeview(self.tabVendors,  style="Mystyle.Treeview",show="tree",selectmode = "extended")
self.tabVendors_tree.column("#0", minwidth=tree_scroll_width, stretch=YES)
self.tabVendors_tree.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
```

Here is screenshot of the resulting tree:

[image: screenshot of tree structure]

In the example, I can control the indentation of "ACTION SOFTWARE" and "AMERICAN SOFT." by using the style.configure. But I can't seem to change the indentation of the children below those entries.

**Update:** What I have noticed is that changing the `indent=` does change the lower level children indentations. For example, if I set `indent=75`, the lower level children are indented. But there seems to be a minimum indention number for lower level children. If I set `indent=0`, then the second level children line up under the parent, but the lower level children are still indented (line up under the first character of parent above them).

I'm wondering if this might be related to the open/close `indicator` not being present for the lower level children?

Here is a code snippet that can be used to test this scenario.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

windowFrame = Frame(win, relief=RIDGE)
windowFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

tabbed_Frame = Frame(windowFrame)
tabbed_Frame.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH, expand=YES )
navFrame = Frame(tabbed_Frame, padx=4, pady=4, borderwidth=1, relief=SUNKEN)
navFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
dbLabel = Label(navFrame)
dbLabel.pack(side=TOP, pady=2,anchor=W)
dbLabel["text"] = "Active database:"
dbSelect = ttk.Combobox(navFrame, width=37,
                    values=["TEST.QDB"])
dbSelect.pack(side=TOP, pady=2,anchor=W)

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Mystyle.Treeview",  indent=15 , bd=0)
style.layout("Mystyle.Treeview", [('Mystyle.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]) # Remove the borders

tree_width=500
NBframe = Frame(navFrame)
NBframe.pack(expand = TRUE, fill=Y)

NBframe_h_scrollbar = Scrollbar(NBframe, orient='horizontal')
NBframe_h_scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
NBframe_v_scrollbar = Scrollbar(NBframe, orient='vertical')
NBframe_v_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

navControl = ttk.Notebook(NBframe)
navControl.pack(expand = TRUE, fill=Y)
tabVendors = Frame(navControl, background="white", borderwidth=1, relief=None, width=250)
tabVendors.pack()
Vendors_tab_name = "Vendors"
navControl.add(tabVendors, text=Vendors_tab_name)
Vendors_tab_index = navControl.index(tabVendors)
tabVendors_tree = ttk.Treeview(tabVendors,show="tree",style="Mystyle.Treeview", selectmode = "extended")
tabVendors_tree.column("#0", minwidth=tree_width, stretch=YES)
tabVendors_tree.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, expand=YES,fill=Y)

NBframe_v_scrollbar.config(command=tabVendors_tree.yview)
NBframe_h_scrollbar.config(command=tabVendors_tree.xview)

tabVendors_tree.config(yscrollcommand = NBframe_v_scrollbar.set)
tabVendors_tree.config(xscrollcommand = NBframe_h_scrollbar.set)

tabProducts = Frame(navControl,background="white",borderwidth=1,relief=RAISED, width=230)
tabProducts.pack()
Products_tab_name = "Products"
navControl.add(tabProducts, text = Products_tab_name)
Products_tab_index = navControl.index(tabProducts)
tabProducts_tree = ttk.Treeview(tabProducts, style="Mystyle.Treeview", show="tree",selectmode = "extended",  yscrollcommand = NBframe_v_scrollbar.set)
tabProducts_tree.column("#0", minwidth=tree_width, stretch=YES)
tabProducts_tree.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, expand=YES, fill=Y)

tabVendors_tree.insert("", "end", "Level1", text="Level-1")
index=0
for i in range(0, 5):

    tree_item=tabVendors_tree.insert("Level1", "end", index, text = "Level-2-"+str(i))
    index+=1
    for j in range (0,20):

        tabVendors_tree.insert(tree_item, "end", index, text="Level-2-"+ str(i) + '-' + str(j) + 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy')
        index+=1

win.mainloop()
quit()
```

Is there another option that I am overlooking?

UPDATE:

Here is an image of the test code with `style.configure("Mystyle.Treeview",  indent=15 , bd=0)`. This causes the open/close box for Level-2-0 to align under the "L" in its parent, Level-1. My goal is to get the "Level-2-0-0xxxx...." entry (highlighted) to align under the  "L in its 'Level-2-0' parent entry above it. However, it is still indented. It seems that there is a minimum indention for the lowest level children.

[image]

Comment: The link to the screen snippet in your question doesn't work.

Comment: @martineau - Sorry about that. When I copied the link from Google Drive I didn't click on the sharing option. Hopefully it's working correctly now.

Comment: It's best to upload images to https://imgur.com via the "add image" editing tool (Ctrl-G) rather than putting them in your personal Google Drive (which might quit working someday). You're also more likely to get helpful answer if you provide a [mre] others can run.

Comment: @martineau - Thanks - I am somewhat new to stackoverflow so don't know the best approaches. Appreciate your feedback. I have added a minimal reproducible example to the original post.

Comment: When I run the snippet you added, the indention for all the child levels **is** the same as what it set in the call to `style.configure()` so I don't understand what you're asking (because that's what you say you want).

Comment: @martineau - Thanks. I updated the question with an example of the test code to hopefully demonstrate what I would like to accomplish. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Oh, OK, I think that's clear - the problem is there's only one indentation level per style and it applies to all the levels, so unfortunately I don't think you can do what you want.

Comment: @martineau - Thanks. That makes sense. Appreciate your help and advice on how to submit questions to stack overflow.